# Sound quality issues when using NAudio to play several wav files at once

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

My objective is this: to allow users of my .NET program to choose their own .wav files for sound effects. These effects may be played simultaneously. NAudio seemed like my best bet.

I decided to use WaveMixerStream32. One early challenge was that my users had .wav files of different formats, so to be able to mix them together with WaveMixerStream32, I needed to "normalize" them to a common format. I wasn't able to find a good example of this to follow so I suspect my problem is a result of my doing this part wrong.

My problem is that when some sounds are played, there are very noticeable "clicking" sounds at their end. I can reproduce this myself.

Also, my users have complained that sometimes, sounds aren't played at all, or are "scratchy" all the way through. I haven't been able to reproduce this in development but I have heard this for myself in our production environment.

I've played the user's wav files myself using Windows Media and VLC, so I know the files aren't corrupt. It must be a problem with how I'm using them with NAudio.

My NAudio version is v1.4.0.0.

Here's the code I used. To set up the mixer:

```
_mixer = new WaveMixerStream32 { AutoStop = false, };
_waveOutDevice = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.NewWindow())
{
    DeviceNumber = -1,
    DesiredLatency = 300,
    NumberOfBuffers = 3,
};
_waveOutDevice.Init(_mixer);
_waveOutDevice.Play();
```

Surprisingly, if I set "NumberOfBuffers" to 2 here I found that sound quality was awful, with audible "ticks" occurring several times a second.

To initialize a sound file, I did this:

```
var sample = new AudioSample(fileName);
sample.Position = sample.Length; // To prevent the sample from playing right away
_mixer.AddInputStream(sample);
```

AudioSample is my class. Its constructor is responsible for the "normalization" of the wav file format. It looks like this:

```
private class AudioSample : WaveStream
{
private readonly WaveChannel32 _channelStream;
public AudioSample(string fileName)
{
    MemoryStream memStream;
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        memStream = new MemoryStream();
        memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    }
    WaveStream originalStream = new WaveFileReader(memStream);
    var pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(originalStream);
    var blockAlignReductionStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcmStream);
    var waveFormatConversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(
        new WaveFormat(44100, blockAlignReductionStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, 2), blockAlignReductionStream);
    var waveOffsetStream = new WaveOffsetStream(waveFormatConversionStream);
    _channelStream = new WaveChannel32(waveOffsetStream);
}
```

Basically, the AudioSample delegates to its _channelStream object. To play an AudioSample, my code sets its "Position" to 0. This code that does this is marshalled onto the UI thread.

This *almost* works great. I can play multiple sounds simultaneously. Unfortunately the sound quality is bad as described above. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points in response to your question:

- Yes, you have to have all inputs at the same sample rate before you feed them into a mixer. This is simply how digital audio works. The ACM sample rate conversion provided by WaveFormatConversion stream isn't brilliant (has no aliasing protection). What sample rates are your input files typically at?
- You are passing every input through two WaveFormatConversionStreams. Only do this if it is absolutely necessary.
- I'm surprised that you are getting bad sound with NumberOfBuffers=2, which is now the default in NAudio. Have you been pausing and resuming, because there was a bug where a buffer could get dropped (fixed in the latest and will be fixed for NAudio 1.4 final)
- A click at the end of a file can just mean it doesn't end on a zero sample. You would have to add a fade out to eliminate this (a lot of media players do this automatically)
- Whenever you are troubleshooting a bad sound issue, I always recommend using WaveFileWriter to convert your WaveStream into a WAV file (taking care not to produce a never ending file!), so you can listen to it in another media player. This allows you to quickly determine whether it is your audio processing that is causing the problem, or the playback itself.

Comment: I really appreciate your response, Mark! I'm not an expert at digital audio but I will try to answer your questions as sensibly as I can. #1 The wav files used by my users have sample rates of 11025, 22000, and 32000 Hz (at least; they're not all under my control).

Comment: I thought I needed the two WaveFormatConversionStream-s, first to take care of files that have variable-rate encoding, and second to take care of getting them all to the same rate. I'd love to hear that I'm doing this wrong :) I'm unsure whether I'm using the latest v1.4 NAudio; the version says 1.4.0.0. Its md5 is 8e5ee2282342b87fa489beda9c6140b0. I'll try to use the latest and see if there's a difference. Your recommendation to add a fade out makes sense; do you know of a good example of doing this with NAudio? I'll look around too. And I really appreciate your WaveFileWriter recommendation.

Comment: I looked at the MD5 of the v1.4 RC, available at http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/64830, and it's the same. I'm definitely using that one.

Comment: the CreatePcmStream function will actually return its input parameter directly if it is not needed, but the second, you should only do if your input is not 44.1kHz. 1.4RC is the latest. You can download what is in SourceControl if you like. I am working on an easier way to construct pipelines of 32 bit floating point audio. I'm currently adding a drum machine sample to the WPF project which will serve as a mixing demo once it is done. I haven't written a fade-out example, but might consider adding one for NAudio 1.5

Comment: I think I have three things to try then: download the latest NAudio source and see if that allows me to use NumberOfBuffers=2; add a fade-out to the post-conversion streams and see if that eliminates the ending "click" sound; dump the transformed streams to new wav files using WaveFileWriter and confirm in an external player that the transformations did what I expected. I'll do just that!